# I want to uninstall netperf 2.6.0 on ubuntu with linux kernel 3.2.21

Tags: uninstall

I had installed netperf 2.5.0 through apt-get install netperf .but i have netperf 2.6.0 on other PC .So i want to uninstall 2.5.0 and reinstall 2.6.0.Kindly Help me .i am using ubuntu with kernel 3.2.21

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your internet connection is on (Wired or Wireless).

Start a root shell using `sudo -i` and follow the instruction. Now type `apt-get remove netperf` then `exit` to drop root privilege